# Show that $\sum_n (1-e^{-1/n})$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis

I'm stuck in showing that $\sum_n (1-e^{-1/n})$ diverges. The ratio and the root test are inconclusive. Possibly the comparison test is the way to go, but I can't find a proper bound. I got

$$
1-\frac{1}{e^{1/n}}>1-\frac{1}{2^{1/n}}
$$

but still I can't see here if the last implied series diverges.

Comment: *Hint*: $1-e^{-1/n}\sim 1/n$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want an inequality about the exponential function,
$$ e^x\ge 1+x$$
is your best friend. So
$$ e^{\frac1n}\ge 1+\frac1n=\frac{n+1}{n}$$
and
$$e^{-\frac1n}=\frac1{e^{\frac1n}}\le \frac n{n+1}=1-\frac1{n+1},$$
making
$$ 1-e^{-\frac1n}\ge \frac1{n+1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the integrand as
$$
e^{\log \big(\frac{\exp(\frac{1}{n}) -1}{\exp(\frac{1}{n})}\big)}  = e^{\log (e^{\frac{1}{n}}-1) - \frac{1}{n}} > e^{0-\frac{1}{n}}
$$
since $\forall n>0 \ \ e^{\frac{1}{n}}>1$ hence $\log$ is positive. This can be compared to the corresponding integral:
$$
\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{x}}dx
$$
which diverges.